# Xbox 360 Wireless Controller is not working via C++/WinRT and Windows.Gaming.Input API in console application

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I trying to use [`Windows.Gaming.Input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input) API via [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) from Windows Console Application and it is not working as supposed with **`Xbox 360 Wireless Controller`** (reported as `Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows (0x045e:0x0000)`).

I got `GamepadAdded` event, then trying to read gamepad state via `gamepad.GetCurrentReading()` and seems `GamepadReading` struct is not filled at all for **`Xbox 360 Wireless Controller`**.

Also I found that there is some strange error message on MSVS debug console:

```
onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpdevicewatcher.cpp(500)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!00007FFE453AABC7: (caller: 00007FFE453AA367) ReturnHr(1) tid(4e04) 80070006 The handle is invalid.
```

`Xbox One Game Controller (0x045e:0x02d1)` is working fine though.

[image]

What is wrong with my code? Or this is bug in Windows?

Code is here: https://github.com/DJm00n/cppwinrtgamepad

Using Windows 10 1809, MSVS 2017 15.9.9, cppwinrt v1.0.190211.5, Windows SDK v10.0.17763.0, `xusb22.sys` v10.0.17163.1, `xboxgip.sys` v10.0.17163.1.

PS: I also tried UWP `Simple3DGameXaml` app from https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples repo - and both controllers works in it.

Comment: I am confirming this issue with the product team and I will update the comment if there are any updates.

Comment: I submitted issue to MS via Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/AA5n0lv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. Apparently this is caused by how focus handling works. Windows.Gaming.Input basically doesn't work for console apps as a result, but does work for Win32 or UWP apps that have a window in focus.

> Note that the one case where the Xbox One controller worked for you is only because both the user was an admin -and- because you had developer mode enabled. It wouldn't work from a console app at all otherwise.

If you need game controller support for a legacy Win32 console app, you should use XINPUT. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/xinput-and-windows-8/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated my code at https://github.com/DJm00n/cppwinrtgamepad and now it working!

Answer (score 0):

In order to help us investigate this issue more clearly, could you please share your Visual Studio 2017 version to us? You can get version info selecting Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio, then selecting Copy Info from the right side of the About dialogue.

Could you please check if you can reproduce this issue on 1903 with SDK 18362?

By the way, it will be better if you can upgrade your project dependencies as well, what you are using is an old version of the Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT NuGet package: 1.0.190211.5. The current latest stable version is v2.0.190722.3.

Besides, the C++ Language Standard was set in project properties, but the value was not set. This should be set to ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17) under Project Properties -> C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard.

Thanks for your collaboration.

Comment: I updated my code on github with CppWinRT 2.0.190730.2 and C++17.
Compiled it with Visual Studio Professional 2017 15.9.14
Here is full info: https://pastebin.com/CjhzUR4C

Comment: Some testing results with my exe (built with SDK 10.0.17763.0 / CppWinRT 2.0.190730.2):

Windows 1809: from user X1 and X360 pads are NOT WORKING. from administrator: X1 pad is OK, X360 pad is NOT WORKING.

Windows 1903: from user and from administrator X1 and X360 pads are NOT WORKING.

Comment: build with SDK 10.0.18362.0 / CppWinRT 2.0.190730.2: same results as with SDK 10.0.17763.0.

Comment: I uploaded exes that I used to test to my repo: https://github.com/DJm00n/cppwinrtgamepad

Comment: Hi DJm00n,
Can you upload a copy of your Project targeting 18362? The version in the github is done with Visual Studio 2017 targeting a lower build. With that version, when I tried the upgrade for Visual Studio 2019 and retarget to 18362, the build is failing.

Comment: @DavidHollowell-MSFT hi! I updated my code to MS2019, SDK 10.0.18362.0 and fixed build issue. Code is on Github.

Comment: Also I found that there is message on MSVS debug console when I running my exe from non-admin user:
onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpdevice.cpp(506)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!00007FFBE4417B64: (caller: 00007FFBE441AF5A) ReturnHr(1) tid(d250) 80070005 Access is denied.

Comment: And message when running from admin and connecting Xbox 360 gamepad:
onecoreuap\xbox\devices\api\winrt\pnpdevicewatcher.cpp(500)\Windows.Gaming.Input.dll!00007FFBE441ABC7: (caller: 00007FFBE441A367) ReturnHr(2) tid(d250) 80070006 The handle is invalid.

Comment: Hi @DJm00n, I'm trying to run your samples, and neither of them are displaying the button pressess from my Xbox One or Xbox 360 controllers. I tested them in a game just to make sure they were working there, and they are.

Are you still able to reproduce this with the code you linked, where the input from Xbox One Controller is being displayed but the input from the Xbox 360 controller.

Comment: @DavidHollowell-MSFT as Chuck Walbourn [mentioned here](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues/564#issuecomment-528038314):
>Note that the one case where the Xbox One controller worked for you is only because both the user was an admin -and- because you had developer mode enabled. It wouldn't work from a console app at all otherwise.