# What DLLs and libs do I need so I can use `timeBeginPeriod` or other parts of `timeapi.h`?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winmm

Whereas many Windows API functions exist in `Windowsapp.lib` or in API sets (see [this answer to How to declare and link to RoInitialize,RoUninitialize,RoGetActivationFactory and HSTRING Functions in Mingw Gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41141287/788168)), many functions are not [listed as included in WindowsApp.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41141287/788168) or in [the extension APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-extension-apis).

For example, [`timeBeginPeriod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod), which I want to use to set the resolution for `Sleep`.

It is part of `Timeapi`, which is not mentioned anywhere in the list of functions available in WindowsApp.lib or extension APIs. The documentation also does not mention any API set.

- Do I link to `winmm.lib` and `winmm.dll`?
- Do I include `Windows.h` or `timeapi.h`?

How would I know? [RoInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/roapi/nf-roapi-roinitialize#see-also) does not mention a DLL or an API set, but it is available in several.

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: The documentation you link to says "include Windows.h" and "Library Winmm.lib".

Comment: Windowsapp.lib, RoXXX are WinRT. timeBeginPeriod is Win32.

Comment: Looks like you mis-tagged the question, this doesn't seem to be a winapi question

Comment: I'm confused; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod does not explain how to use it, it just mentions headers and libraries. I get that they're relevant, but I was looking for an example of consuming this information. Also, is this not a WinAPI question? It's about a function that is part of the Windows API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured I'd look into this myself. I wrote a little test program and used the VS compiler to test.

1. Via Start, I launched a VS developer prompt ([among other ways of doing that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160) like in the answer to [Run cl.exe from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831031/788168) ).
2. I wrote up some simple programs to test the various cases.

### The answer

My experimentation showed that the answer to this question is not necessarily straightforward:

> - Do I link to `winmm.lib` and `winmm.dll`?

You may link/consume `winmm`, but `windowsapp.lib` is also sufficient, even though it is not documented that the time API functions are part of it.

> - Do I include `Windows.h` or `timeapi.h`?

At least in my experimentation, *`Windows.h`* was actually required to use `timeBeginPeriod`. `timeapi.h` was not sufficient or necessary. It is unclear to me why that is the case.

---

Here's how I got this answer:

### Compiling a simple program

Just to prove things will compile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

```
>cl /EHsc src\app.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

app.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:app.exe
app.obj


> .\app.exe
Hello!
```

### Consume functions known to exist in Windowsapp.lib

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <winstring.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;

    // Ignore the poor error handling
    HSTRING string;
    WindowsCreateString(L"Test", 4, &string);
    const auto len = WindowsGetStringLen(string);
    std::cout << len << std::endl;
    WindowsDeleteString(string);
}
```

```
> cl /EHsc windowsapp.lib src\app.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

app.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:app.exe
windowsapp.lib
app.obj

> .\app.exe
Hello!
4
```

### Consuming functions time API functions (this question)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
// Interestingly, timeapi.h does not work:
// #include <timeapi.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
    timeBeginPeriod(500);
}
```

Linking winmm.lib:

```
> cl /EHsc winmm.lib src\app.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

app.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:app.exe
winmm.lib
app.obj

> .\app.exe
Hello!
```

Interestingly, you can also link just Windowsapp.lib instead:

```
> cl /EHsc windowsapp.lib src\app.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

app.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:app.exe
windowsapp.lib
app.obj

> .\app.exe
Hello!
```